# Variable Coin Flipping

Tags: probability

You flip a coin 10 times. The probability that the coin lands heads on the $i^{th}$ flip $1\leq i\leq 10$ is equal to $\frac{H+1}{i+1},$ where $H$ is the number of Heads flipped until that point. Which of the following is closets to the probability you will flip exactly 7 heads (1/20, 1/15, 1/12, 1/10, 1/8)?

I was thinking that the probability of 7H, 3T is the probability of HHHHHHHTTT times 10C7, but I get $\frac{720}{990}.$

Comment: The paths are not equally probable, so that computation is not correct.  Note that there are $120$ possible paths so doing them one at a time won't be easy.

Comment: @Lulu I believe the paths are actually equally probable - if you work through a few cases you can see the equivalence